# Grafana passing access token in url

Tags: authentication, grafana

I have created an API Key to share grafana panels with third party applications.
I want to embed it on an iframe but it asks me to login.

How can I send the access token in the url ?

I've been following: http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html#query-param

Example

```
https://server.example.com/resource?access_token=mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM&p=q
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access tokens can only be used with the API, you need to use it in the Authorization HTTP header. It cannot be used in iframe scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. Do you plan to add this functionality ? Will be great for us to be able to share panels in this way using the API tokens.

Comment: Sorry, now I have found: http://docs.grafana.org/v2.0/reference/sharing/#embed-panel
How does it works in terms of security ?